# Unable to connect to ClusterIP service

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, rabbitmq

I've have RabbitMQ deployment with ClusterIP service.

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbit-mq
  name: rabbit-mq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbit-mq
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         app: rabbit-mq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rabbitmq:3.6.1-management
        name: rabbit-mq
        ports:        
        - containerPort: 5672
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
          name: rabbit-mq-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      hostname: rabbit-mq
      volumes:
      - name: rabbit-mq-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: rabbit-mq-data
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbit-mq-service
  labels:
    app: rabbit-mq
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5672    
  selector:
   app: rabbit-mq
```

As I tested with other services and as it says in documentation, ClusterIP service should be visible to all pods and nodes inside cluster.
I need my RabbitMQ service to be accessible only inside cluster.
As I defined port 5672, same is used for targetPort.

I have .NET Core application connecting to service with following connection string: 
`amqp://user:password@10.100.10.10:5672/`

`kubectl get svc rabbit-mq-service`

`NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
rabbit-mq-service   ClusterIP   10.100.10.10   <none>        5672/TCP   3h7m`

When I try to connect to RabbitMQ, I get the error:

`Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.`

Have I misunderstood how ClusterIP service works?

Comment: Is ClusterIP required or you can go with headless service?

Comment: I think, you are missing `targetPort` in service deployment.

Comment: @FL3SH It's not required, I can go with any solution as longs as it's not accessible from outside cluster.

Comment: @Nirav I think targetPort is implied if I have 'port' field. Documentation says so. I could try it either way.

Comment: `targetPort` is optional as long as `port == targetPort`

Comment: Ah, my bad. I did not know that. Thank you @FL3SH and Andrija\

Comment: btw, this is hosted on AWS, if it makes any difference.

Comment: I tried ClusterIP deployment with nginx from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/ , it works. The difference is port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbit-mq-service
  labels:
    app: rabbit-mq
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 5672    
  selector:
   app: rabbit-mq
```

and `amqp://user:password@rabbit-mq-service:5672/`

Comment: `The Service "rabbit-mq-service" is invalid: spec.type: Unsupported value: "None": supported values: "ClusterIP", "ExternalName", "LoadBalancer", "NodePort"`

Comment: It doesn't work `Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.`

Comment: It should work, are you sure that rabbitmq container is listening on port 5672? Maybe try with docker and then move to k8s.

Comment: `NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE 
rabbit-mq-service   ClusterIP   None         <none>        5672/TCP   36m`

Comment: Container, not service. Exec into pod and run `netstat` or `ss`

Comment: It seems there is nothing listening on 5672 port when I run `ss -l`

Comment: I recreated rabbitmq, it is listening now on 5672, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that old container image was cached and it was not pulling new image with new config, new config we are discussing here. I made a new image tag and now it works, but in meantime I created NodePort service instead while I was troubleshooting. I still need to test with your headless service. I still have no idea how to refresh image on remote machine without re-tagging.

Comment: @Andrija I'm facing the same issue but I'm updating my appsettings.json file with configmap. Any suggestions?